# Scroll bars that fit content window

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix my webpages so I can scroll the dynamic content of different pages. I 'fixed' the header, footer, and sidebar. I've tried with overflow: auto, overflow: scroll; etc. but they aren't working correctly. Some pages I can't see the entire content. I'm not a professional, I'm an enthusiast trying to create and maintain a couple of different sites. (No, my Toastmasters wouldn't pay for a pro even if they DID have the money.

I was fascinated with a fiddle I found, which uses no overflow at all.
It originally had no footer, which I added to accurately simulate what happens on my site. Notice the scroll bars continue to the side of the header and footer.

http://jsfiddle.net/inquii/Nrs2u/4/

#### CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;

}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

.static {
    width:996px;
    z-index:2;
    height:150px;
    position: fixed;
}

#header {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    height: 172px;
    width: 996px;
    min-width: 850px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-image: url(images/wga_banner.jpg);
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
}


#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 994px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 202px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 700px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 202px;
    bottom: 35px;
}

.main_content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 752px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    color: #000;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #A9B2B1;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 202px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


.container {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 996px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 202px;
}


#footer {
    background-color: #772432;
    clear: both;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 996px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

#### HTML & PHP:

```
<body style="margin: 0; background-color: #A9B2B1;">
<div id="wrapper">
    <?php 
    $path = $_SERVER['toast'];
    $path .= "_includes/header.php";
    include_once($path);
    ?>
    <?php 
    $path = $_SERVER['toast'];
    $path .= "_includes/sidemenu.php";
    include_once($path);
    ?>   
</div>   

<div class="main_content">
    <p>Don't worry; there's no capital punishment during Toastmasters meetings. Unless, of course, the grammarian is in a bad mood.</p>
    <p>If you think of a club meeting as a project, then you can see the  general evaluator as a kind of project manager. As GE, your  responsibilities include:</p>
    <ul type="disc">
      <li>Ensuring the speech and leadership project evaluators know their responsibilities</li>
      <li>Supervising the timer, grammarian and Ah-Counter</li>
      <li>Evaluating everything that takes place during the club meeting </li>
      <li>Making sure each activity is performed correctly</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Several days before the meeting, contact the person who will be  Toastmaster of the meeting and confirm the meeting program. You should  also develop a checklist to follow during the meeting so you don't have  to keep all the details in your head. Some clubs have a prepared  checklist. If your club doesn't have one, ask the Toastmaster to help  you create your own checklist.</p>
    <p>When discussing the meeting program with the Toastmaster, ask what  evaluation format to use. Typically, an evaluator is assigned to an  individual, but sometimes evaluations are done by panels. The general  evaluator may set up any evaluation procedure he or she chooses, but it  should fit into the meeting program. Remember, too, that every  evaluation must be brief and complete. Review the <em>Effective Evaluation</em> manual for different evaluation formats.</p>
    <p>You'll also need to contact members serving as:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Timer</li>
      <li>Grammarian</li>
      <li>Ah-Counter </li>
      <li>Individual evaluators</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Remind them of their assignments, and brief evaluators on their  responsibilities, the members they will evaluate and the evaluation  format to use. Make sure the evaluators understand that evaluation is a  positive, helping act that enables fellow Toastmasters to develop their  skills. Point out that an evaluation should enhance the speaker's  self-esteem and encourage evaluators to prepare thoroughly for their  role. Recommend that they call the member they've been assigned to  evaluate to discuss specific project objectives.</p>
    <p>Your final task <em>before</em> the meeting is to prepare a brief verbal explanation detailing:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>The purpose, techniques and benefits of evaluation so guests and new  members will better understand the function of evaluations. </li>
      <li>How evaluation is a positive experience designed to help people overcome flaws and reinforce good habits in their presentations.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>On meeting day:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Arrive early. </li>
      <li>Make sure all evaluators are present and that they have the appropriate speaker or leader's manual. </li>
      <li>If an evaluator is absent, consult with the vice president education and arrange for a substitute. </li>
      <li>Ask each evaluator if he or she has any questions about the project  objectives to be evaluated, verify each speaker's time and notify the  timer if there are any changes. </li>
      <li>Take your seat near the back of the room. This will ensure you have a good view of the meeting and all its participants.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>The Toastmaster of the meeting usually introduces the general  evaluator before the Table Topics portion of the meeting. But your club  may have a different order for introductions, so check with the  Toastmaster or VPE before the meeting if you're not sure when you'll be  introduced.</p>
    <p>When you're introduced:</p>
    <ul type="disc">
      <li>Stand by your chair and deliver the explanation you prepared. </li>
      <li>Identify the grammarian, Ah-Counter and timer and have these members briefly state the purpose of their jobs. </li>
      <li>Request the word of the day, if your club has one, from the grammarian and then be seated.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>During the meeting, use your checklist and take notes on everything  that happens (or doesn't, but should). For example: Is the club's  property (e.g. trophies, banner, educational material) properly  displayed? Were there unnecessary distractions that could have been  avoided? Did the meeting, and each segment of it, begin and end on time?</p>
    <p>Study each participant on the program, from the person giving the  invocation or thought for the day to the last report by the timer. Look  for good and less than desirable examples of preparation, organization,  delivery, enthusiasm, observation and general performance of duties.  When it's time to begin the evaluation portion of the meeting, the  Toastmaster will introduce you, again. This time, you'll go to the  lectern and introduce each evaluator. After each recitation, thank the  evaluator for his or her efforts.</p>
    <p>Finally, give your general evaluation of the meeting:</p>
    <ul type="disc">
      <li>Use your checklist and the notes you took during the meeting. </li>
      <li>Phrase your evaluation so it is helpful, encouraging and motivates club members to implement the suggestions. </li>
      <li>You may wish to comment on the quality of evaluations. Were they  positive, upbeat, helpful? Did they point the way to improvement? </li>
      <li>When you've completed your evaluation, return control of the meeting to the Toastmaster.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Being general evaluator is a big responsibility and it is integral to  the success of every single club member. People join Toastmasters  because they have a goal – they want to learn something. The club is  where they learn. If the learning environment isn't focused and fun,  members won't learn what they joined to learn. Your observations and  suggestions help ensure the club is meeting the goals and needs of each  member.</p>
    <p>And what do <em>you</em> get out of the deal? You get the chance to  practice and improve your skills in critical thinking, planning,  preparation and organization, time management, motivation and team  building!</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- ends container-->


<?php 
   $path = $_SERVER['toast'];
   $path .= "_includes/footer.php";
   include_once($path);
?>
</div> <!-- ends wrapper-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
var MenuBar2 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar2", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, use http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate your code. It's impossible to figure out what are you talking about without demo.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion so far. This is my first time figuring out the stack overflow process of submitting questions, code, etc.

Comment: In future, please keep different languages in separate blocks (i.e. CSS in one code block, HTML & PHP in the other) as it makes it easier to understand and ensures the syntax highlighting works correctly. I submitted an edit that should be approved soon.

Comment: @MichaelM.Kalygin Agreed, could the OP please use a jsFiddle to demonstrate what you mean as it is difficult to see what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: so what exactly is your question? you seem to have an example in a fiddle of what you want to do. what do you need from us?

Comment: @ Bobo Sorry, my internet was down for 3 days.I have found several answers that came very close. Whoever said I did no research was mistaken. I'

Answer (score 2):

Didn't quite get what you mean, but I fixed to this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nrs2u/7/)

It was the same, I just removed the following CSS rule:

```css
body {
    height: 300%;
}
```

Comment: I was also in doubt as to what he wanted. I'd suggest just removing the height of this style.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'll try to explain. The scroll bar starts at the top of the header and stops at the bottom of the footer. If you look at the content in the HTML, the last statement is Content Last. With the jsFiddle I can't scroll down far enough to see that statement.

Comment: @Alex This still doesn't show the last item in the list. After all the Content Here items I finished with Content Last. This doesn't scroll far enough down to see that item.

Comment: sorry I can see Content Last in there  jsfiddle.net/Nrs2u/7

Comment: I'm using FF and Safari and Content Last doesn't show in either of those browsers.

Comment: If are not sure on what you trying to achieve no one can help u with that :)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/inquii/Nrs2u/10 displays all the content correctly. I would prefer the scroll bar start underneath the header and stop above the footer and not be positioned outside the entire footer/content/header/ window.:)